# How can I use puppet in my system

Tags: tomcat, puppet

I have a system with two Tomcat servers A and B (on Windows-64-bit, 8 GB RAM). And Apache web server as load balancer proxy server pointing to A and B.
If I want to use puppet in the existing system. Is it helpful? What will be the benefit of using it. Is there any other configuration management software available.
Thanks in advance for any help in this regard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to decide if puppet is the right tool to fit your needs have. Please have a look at the puppet description at https://puppetlabs.com/puppet/what-is-puppet/

There are many other config management tools out there (cfengine, chef,...)